# How can I change the parameter of the url in data-click attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML element which has a data-click attribute with the below string. I want to change the src value inside the string. How to do it with javascript in such a way that it works for all similar strings.  Can someone help me?

Tried regex but not sure if it works for all.

```
"Meetings.renderMiniPopup('/p/p1/meetings/mini_popup?member_id=55218&src=nuxgml')"
```

Comment: Can you please show what regex you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of Regex and the [**replace**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```
str.replace( /(Meetings\.renderMiniPopup\(')([^']*)('\))/ , '$1'+ '<MY NEW VALUE HERE>' +'$3' )
```